# Need help solving an assignment

Tags: c++

I have the following assignment:

> We have the length of four sides. You have to determine if they can form a square. If not, determine if they can form a rectangle. If not, determine if they can form a quadrangle
>
> Hints
>
> Sorting the lengths will help us , so
>
> `If L1 == L2 && L2 == L3 && L3 == L4` this will be square
>
> `If L1 == L2 && L3 == L4` this will be rectangle
>
> `If L1 + L2 + L3 > L4` this will be quadrangle
>
> If it isn't one of them we will call it banana
>
> Input:
>
> The number of test cases, following a line with four positive integer numbers, between 0 and 2^30, the lengths.
>
> Output:
>
> One of four strings: ‘square’, ‘rectangle’, ‘quadrangle’ or ‘banana’.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4
> 10 8 7 6
> 9 1 9 1
> 29 29 29 29
> 5 12 13 7
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> quadrangle
> rectangle
> square
> ```

I don't know how to solve this.  Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int L1; int L2; int L3; int L4;
    cin>>L1>>L2>>L3>>L4;

    cout<<"Enter the 4 lengths";

    if(L1 == L2 && L2 == L3 && L3 == L4){
        cout<<"You have choosed the square";
    }
    else if(L1 == L2 && L3 == L4|| L1==L3 && L2==L4){
        cout<<"You have choosed the rectangle";
    }
    else if(L1 + L2 + L3 > L4){
        cout<<"You have choosed the quadrangle";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"It's Baanana";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did notice word "sorting" in the hint, right?

Comment: The problem in sorting could anyone help me fix that ?

Comment: You are not reading any input from the user.  You can't sort what you don't have.

Comment: Can you put the full right code with sorting pls ?

Comment: oooh yeeh i did miss this line from my code
 cin>>L1>>L2>>L3>>L4;
        sorry i didnt copy it from my compiler but i still need to know how to sorting it

Comment: Are you allowed to use STL algorithms?  Look at [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not <strike>reading any input from the user, let alone</strike> sorting the input.  Also, you are not following the first requirement mentioned in the assignment, either (reading the number of test cases).

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define L1 Lengths[0]
#define L2 Lengths[1]
#define L3 Lengths[2]
#define L4 Lengths[3]

int main()
{
    int NumTestCases, Lengths[4];

    cout << "How many test cases? ";
    cin >> NumTestCases;

    for(int i = 0; i < NumTestCases; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter 4 lengths: ";
        cin >> L1 >> L2 >> L3 >> L4;
        std::sort(Lengths, Lengths+4);

        if ((L1 == L2) && (L2 == L3) && (L3 == L4)) {
            cout << "square" << endl;
        }
        else if (((L1 == L2) && (L3 == L4)) || ((L1 == L3) && (L2 == L4))) {
            cout << "rectangle" << endl;
        }
        else if ((L1 + L2 + L3) > L4) {
            cout << "quadrangle" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "banana" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are da king :D <3